# Website Continously loading but nothing show

Tags: magento-1.9

When i hit main domain name or any other page link website starts loading but it shows nothing and keep loading.its magento 1..Any luck

[image]

Comment: can you provide frontend url ?

Comment: Here it is Mukesh http://dev.itechdevices.co.uk/

Comment: any error or log ?

Comment: enabled error reporting ?

Comment: error reporting is enable but no error reporting

Answer (score 0):

You can try with followings points.

```
1. Check with core_config_data table with following path filed.
-> web/unsecure/base_url // your domain name
-> web/secure/base_url   // Your domain name.

2. Removed the value of web/cookie/cookie_domain and set web/cookie/cookie_httponly to 0

3. Cleared Cache & try.
```